# android how to open facebook app if it is installed in the phone

Tags: android, facebook

I would like to open the Facebook application from my application. If it is installed then I would like to open Facebook application window, not the popup window of Facebook.

How can I do that?

Comment: How can you open the Facebook application window if it is not installed?

Comment: no, if installed how can i open the App window not the popup window

Comment: What popup window? If the application is not installed, you **cannot** open the application. The best you can do is show the user an alert indicating that the application is not installed.

Comment: sory , after install only i want to open the facebbok app , how can i ?

Comment: did u see that popup it will come u can signin then that popup will go and u come to our app, i dont wnat that. I want on a button click it should open the facebook app which is installed on the phone.

Comment: How are you invoking the facebook application. Could you post some code?

Comment: did u see foursquare app

Answer (score 0):

It's presented in Facebook Android SDK. When You need to proceed with FB login, the SDK opens FB App instead of popup alert if installed.

Here's the code (from [Facebook SDK code](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk/blob/master/facebook/src/com/facebook/android/Facebook.java))

```
    /*
    * Copyright 2010 Facebook, Inc.
    *
    * Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
    * you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
    * You may obtain a copy of the License at
    *
    * http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
    *
    * Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
    * distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
    * WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
    * See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
    * limitations under the License.
    */
public class Facebook {
...

        /**
        * Internal method to handle single sign-on backend for authorize().
        */
            private boolean startSingleSignOn(Activity activity, String applicationId,
                    String[] permissions, int activityCode) {
                boolean didSucceed = true;
                Intent intent = new Intent();

                intent.setClassName("com.facebook.katana",
                        "com.facebook.katana.ProxyAuth");
                intent.putExtra("client_id", applicationId);
                if (permissions.length > 0) {
                    intent.putExtra("scope", TextUtils.join(",", permissions));
                }

                // Verify that the application whose package name is
                // com.facebook.katana.ProxyAuth
                // has the expected FB app signature.
                if (!validateAppSignatureForIntent(activity, intent)) {
                    return false;
                }

                mAuthActivity = activity;
                mAuthPermissions = permissions;
                mAuthActivityCode = activityCode;
                try {
                    activity.startActivityForResult(intent, activityCode);
                } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
                    didSucceed = false;
                }

                return didSucceed;
            }
...
}
```

Comment: where i ll get application id?

Comment: @Jyosna sandrstar posted a code snippet from the Facebook SDK. You don't need to worry how it works. Sandrstar's point is that you cannot navigate to the facebook application without signing in.

Comment: ya that one i have, but i want from my application button click it should go to the facebook app, how can i do that

Comment: One way is to install the Fb app when you install your own application, so then u wont need to download because its already done.

Comment: @Joysna for more details about FB SDK - check out https://developers.facebook.com/docs/mobile/android/build/